# GROUP BY, HAVING, and COUNT to get aggregated results

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, having

I have seen a few threads about using these three functions but I can't get the results I want based on what I read.

I am using SQL SERVER 2012. The table is APXFirm.AdvApp.vPerformance
Here is the table schema

[image: table schema]
I tried the following query:

```
USE APXFirm
SELECT PortfolioBaseCode
 ,COUNT(  portfoliobasecode) AS Pcount
  FROM APXFirm.AdvApp.vPerformance
        WHERE rowtypecode = 'd'   
        and DetailKeyCode is NOT NULL
        and NetOrGrossCode = 'n'
and DetailKeyCode <> 'us'
and PortfolioBaseCode IN ('test','test2')
GROUP BY PortfolioBaseCode,
      NetOrGrossCode, 
            RowTypeCode ,
           DetailKeyCode ,
           MarketValue 
 HAVING marketvalue > 1
```

But this gives me a result like this:

```
PortfolioBaseCode   Pcount
test                 1
test                 1
test                 1
test2                1
test2                1
test2                1
test2                1
```

I want a result like this

```
PortfolioBaseCode   Pcount
test                 3
test2                4
```

I'm not sure if I need a subquery, a join or to use distinct in the count to achieve this or something else. I did also try this line but it didn't change the result.

```
 ,COUNT( DISTINCT portfoliobasecode) AS Pcount
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many columns in the `group by`.  I think you just want:

```
SELECT PortfolioBaseCode, COUNT(  portfoliobasecode) AS Pcount
FROM APXFirm.AdvApp.vPerformance
WHERE rowtypecode = 'd' AND  
      DetailKeyCode is NOT NULL AND
      NetOrGrossCode = 'n' AND
      DetailKeyCode <> 'us' AND
      PortfolioBaseCode IN ('test', 'test2')
GROUP BY PortfolioBaseCode
HAVING SUM(marketvalue) > 1;
```

I'm actually not sure what the `HAVING` clause is supposed to be doing.  Perhaps you can remove it.  Perhaps you can move the logic `marketvalue > 1` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This query aggregates everything into one line and shows the first portfoliobasecode only. In this case Test so I get a result  Test 3

Comment: @JayC . . . This should produce one row for each value of `PortfolioBaseCode`, which seems to be be what you want.  If you ware only getting one value, then the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses are filtering everything else out.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
HAVING marketvalue > 1
```

with

```
HAVING Pcount > 1
```